# How to understand the differences between CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH and CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH in the right way?

Tags: cmake

As per the [document](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH.html#variable:CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH), which says:

> CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH¶ New in version 3.8.
>
> Semicolon-separated list specifying runtime path (RPATH) entries to
> add to binaries linked in the build tree (for platforms that support
> it). The entries will not be used for binaries in the install tree.
> See also the CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH variable.
>
> This is used to initialize the BUILD_RPATH target property for all
> targets.

As per the [document](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH.html), which says:

> CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH¶ The rpath to use for installed targets.
>
> A semicolon-separated list specifying the rpath to use in installed
> targets (for platforms that support it). This is used to initialize
> the target property INSTALL_RPATH for all targets.

How to understand the differences between `CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH` and `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` in the right way?

A small and clear example is welcome.

Comment: Do you know what are **build tree** and **install tree** of the project? If yes, then what is unclear in that descriptions? Libraries and executables in the build tree will have RPATH from the `CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH`. Once installed, those libraries and executables will have RPATH from `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I see. The `installed targets` confuses me mostly. Thank you for the reply. I think `intalled targets` are the targets that would be put in the ***install tree***. Am I right? I googled and found that [the ***build tree*** is the directory hierarchy in which all generated files are placed](http://ecos.sourceware.org/docs-latest/user-guide/build-tree.html).  I didn't find the definition of the ***install tree***, I guess the ***install tree*** is the directory hierarchy in which generated files would be installed.

Comment: "The `installed targets` confuses me mostly." - This is the **actual problem**. isn't it? Why do not ask **explicitly** about it? The "install tree" is the hierarchy of files and directories created upon installation of the project. Only those files and directories can be used after the project is deployed; source files and build files can be safely removed after the installation. Not sure what is the meaning of "installed targets" in the documentation. Probably they refer to targets in automatically generated installation CMake script. But those are internals of CMake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building binaries one can set the RPATH to support library path resolution at runtime.

There are two scenarios for which to build binaries. The first an obvious scenario is to debug a program. This means the binary will be built and (normally) executed from the location it has been built. Details can vary but in general it is under the [cmake build directory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR.html#cmake-current-binary-dir).

This means if you build for example two libraries in your project `libA` and `libB`. `libA` dynamically linking `libB`. This means both libraries are located somewhere in the binary path. To run a binary in the build path with runtime dependency resolution you CAN specify the [CMAKE_BUILD_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH.html?highlight=cmake_build_rpath#cmake-build-rpath) or the recommended target property [BUILD_RPATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/BUILD_RPATH.html#prop_tgt:BUILD_RPATH) with an absolute or relative value.

| lib | location | rpath |
| --- | --- | --- |
| libA | /home/user/my_tool/build/liba | *./../libb/* or */home/user/my_tool/build/libb* |
| libB | /home/user/my_tool/build/libb |  |

Then you can smoothly run your binary from the build path and everything should work without modifying the [LD_LIBRARY_PATH](https://linuxhint.com/what-is-ld-library-path/) system environment variable for dependency lookup.

The same applies to the RPATH if the binary gets installed ([cmake install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#install-a-project)). In this case the value of the RPATH could be different. To accommodate this there are these two CMake features to distinguish between the scenarios.

| lib | location | rpath |
| --- | --- | --- |
| libA | /usr/lib/my_tool | *.* or */usr/lib/my_tool* |
| libB | /usr/lib/my_tool |  |

Comment: The /usr/bin in the rpath column of the last table should obviously be /usr/lib